# Speed issues with Multithread in Windows CE/ WinMobile 6.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have an application that is extremely slow for no apparent reason in Windows CE/WindowsMobile 6.1 the application uses threads in a straightforward, I am trying to investigate is this is the cause of the issue, I wrote a simple program:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace SmartDeviceProject6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime mtStart = DateTime.Now;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} MainThread - START", mtStart.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Main Thread - Starts Here!");
            Thread t = new Thread(WriteY);          // Kick off a new thread
            t.Start();                               // running WriteY()

            // Simultaneously, do something on the main thread.
            for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("x");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("x");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteIf(i == 249, "X is OVER");
                if (i == 50)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MAIN - sleep");
                    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            DateTime mtEnd = DateTime.Now;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} MainThread - END", mtEnd.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
        }

        static void WriteY()
        {
            DateTime wtStart = DateTime.Now;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} WorkerThread - START", wtStart.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Worker Thread - Starts Here!");
            for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Y");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Y");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteIf(i == 249, "Y is OVER");
                if (i == 100)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HIT - 100!!!");
                    //Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }

            DateTime wtEnd = DateTime.Now;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} WorkerThread - END", wtEnd.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

> 'SmartDeviceProject6.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\mscorlib.dll'
>   'SmartDeviceProject6.exe' (Managed): Loaded
>   'c:\users\icreate\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\smartdeviceproject6\smartdeviceproject6\bin\debug\SmartDeviceProject6.exe',
>   Symbols loaded. 'SmartDeviceProject6.exe' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.dll'
>   12/06/2012 01:02:36.000 PM: {0} MainThread - START Main Thread -
>   Starts Here! x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
>   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x MAIN - sleep x x x x x x x
>   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
>   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
>   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
>   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
>   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
>   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x X is OVER12/06/2012 01:02:38.000 PM:
>   {0} MainThread - END The thread 0xf6b1b7d6 has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). 12/06/2012 01:02:38.000 PM: {0} WorkerThread - START Worker
>   Thread - Starts Here! Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
>   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
>   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
>   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y HIT - 100!!! Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
>   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
>   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
>   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
>   Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y is OVER12/06/2012
>   01:02:38.000 PM: {0} WorkerThread - END The thread 0x36be0f96 has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0xd7be774a has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). The program '[0xF7D3F6F6] SmartDeviceProject6.exe: Managed' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).

There are two things that trouble me...

1) is that there is no apparent threading going on... All the Xs are printed and then all the Ys, if I do a sleep I can interleave the code, but there appears to be no multi-threading going on...

2) these are a couple of very simple for loops, they should not take one second to run.

Does anyone know if WinMobile 6.1 supports threading in a proper way? Is there a different threading model that I should use? What can I do to speed up things?

Comment: What happens to the timing if you remove the Console call and use a Stopwatch or Environment.Tickcount (which are way more appropriate for timing this kind of thing than DateTime.Now, which only has a 1s resolution on most devices)?

Comment: Changed my code, and I get much different results... I suspected that the writes caused the issue, but I was afraid that having multiple threads writing to the same file would cause lock issues... Also I can't seem to be able to run a console application on winmobile6.1, so i made a poor choice with the Debug.Write I am using a Psion Teklogix 7505 (it's also a PXA270).

Comment: WinMo has no Console, so the output doesn't actually go anywhere (it might redirect to the debug console - I've never bothered to actually look)

Comment: Cool thanks for the heads-up. It's my first time with this kind of device and OS, I also am not a .net programmer to add injury to insult ;) I am trying to get an application to run faster by properlly implementing threads... basically one thread listens for network events to accept a connection, recv some XML, parses it, and  calls a DLL, serializes to xml and sends some data back, using sockets and local to the device... this is taking sometimes 10s for the whole trip, and I am trying to see if poor threading is the cause.

Comment: Async socket handling would probably be a better route than threading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "slowness" you're seeing has to do with your debugger connection.  `Debug.Writeline` is synchronous and slow (`Console.Writeline` isn't all that fast either).  For example, I removed them and counting to 2500 (so 10x larger than your test) in both loops only takes about 80ms on the PXA270 device I have in front of me.  Even writing to a file has little impact on speed.

I did see the same "all one thread then all the other" when I ran flat-out with no yielding, but I can't say I'm overly surprised.  Both threads are at the same priority, and it's likely that the thread quantum is the reason - if you ran a lot more iterations, you'd hit a quantum limit and the scheduler would swap.  I put in a `Thread.Sleep(0)` in each loop and that gives output much more like what you're expecting and the time only increased to about 180ms to run to 2500 (the thread context switches are the slowdown).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start");
        var writer = File.CreateText("\\test.txt");
        var start = Environment.TickCount;
        var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        var t = new Thread(delegate
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++)
                {
                    writer.Write(".");
                    Thread.Sleep(0);
                }
                // set an event signaling completion
                are.Set();
            });
        t.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++)
        {
            writer.Write("+");
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
        var et = Environment.TickCount - start;
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("\r\nET: {0}ms", et));
        // wait for the thread to complete
        are.WaitOne();
        // this would also work
        // t.Join();
        writer.Close();

        using(var reader = File.OpenText("\\test.txt"))
        {
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i change the Thread.Sleep(1000) to Thread.Sleep(1) i get a An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll error... should I use a lock to control access to the file?

Comment: No, that Sleep(1000) just makes the primary thread wait for the worker to be completely finished before shutting down the stream.

Comment: Hi ctacke, great information about Debug.WriteLine, now I know, why my mutlithreaded app becomes slow in a debug session. Regarding the Sleep(1000) I suggest to use a more robust code with a WaitHandle set by the background thread.

Comment: Sure, a WaitHandle would be far more appropriate in real code, or a Thread.Join call.  This was simply a test.

Comment: Can you guys provide sample code with WaitHandle? I am unfamiliar with C# Threading model.

Comment: edited to show using a WaitHandle (AutoResetEvent derives from it)